# Verify if there leading zeros in a filename using ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, leading-zero

I have a directory of files that contain an incrementing value (without leading zeros) in the filename, which I have stored in an array and have then sorted

```
contents = Dir.glob("W:/file path/*.txt").select { |f| f.include?('foo')}.sort_by{|s| s[/(?<=_)\d+/].to_i}
```

file format is

```
W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_1-foo.txt 
W:/name/2014-09-02 - name/20140902-070343_10-foo.txt
```

I’m looking for a way to loop through the array to test if the incrementing values have leading zeros. In this case the test would fail.

Should I be extracting the part of the filename I need as a substring and store in a new array, then loop through verifying if there are leading zeros or not? Would this be done with a regular expression such as `/^00/`?

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean "should be _001" - do you want to rename the files?

Comment: Sorry I removed it as it was misleading

Comment: I'm looking to verify if values contain leading zeros. If they don't, test fails, if they do Test passes

Comment: What about `_100`, should it fail or pass?

Comment: And what about `_01`, is that valid or do you expect `_001`?

Comment: Sorry, that should be _001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, you could simply check if all filenames have 3 digits after `_`:

```
Dir.glob('...').all? { |x| x =~ /_\d{3}/ }
```

Comment: I just realized that you're using this regexp yourself :-)

Comment: Not wanting to add zeros. I'm looking to verify if values contain leading zeros. If they don't, test fails, if they do Test passes

Comment: that worked 'zeros = contents.all? { |z| z =~ /_\d{3}/ } ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL'' what is the =~ doing?

Comment: It tests if the regexp matches, returning the index of the first match or `nil` if there was no match.